# change data provider using radio BUTTONS

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I have this code . I want to change data provider using radio BUTTONS.
how I can make this change, this is my code below

```
        AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "pie",
            "dataProvider": AmCharts.loadJSON('data.php'),
            if (document.getElementById("rb1").checked){
            "dataProvider": AmCharts.loadJSON('data.php'),
            }
            if (document.getElementById("rb2").checked)
            { "dataProvider": AmCharts.loadJSON('databycountry.php'),}

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="20">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" checked="true" name="group" id="rb1" >labels outside
                <input type="radio"  name="group" id="rb2">labels inside</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="chartdiv" align="center" style="width: 50%; align: left;height: 500px;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using onclick handler for the radio button ?

Comment: i do it with function but which parameters i have to passed in funciton

Comment: inside the click handler you will run the chart function.

Comment: function selectDataset() {
  if (document.getElementById("rb1").checked) {
  chart.dataProvider = AmCharts.loadJSON('data.php');
  chart.validateData();
  }
}

Comment: I gave up while writing the code in the box. I don't know how to use this site.
Basically you can test for its value. So if(radio.value=='1'){do something} 
else{do something else}

Comment: <input type='radio' value='1' name='group' onclick='makeChart(this)'>
<input type='radio' value='2' name='group' onclick='makeChart(this)'>
function makeChart(input){
    //input.value
    //do something
}